# Problem with automatic line break in math mode

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I've got a special problem with writing in math mode. In general there is absolutely no problem with, e.g., writing something like

```
$x+x+x++x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x$
```

will produce the required line break, whereas something like

```
The subset $\Xi\subseteq C^{1,\alpha\times C^{0,\alpha}$ is closed with
respect to the $C^{1,\beta}\times C^{0,\beta}$-Topology
```

will write the part `C^{0,\beta}$-Topology` of the text over the end of the line. Here it's important, that this part stands close to the end of a line.
In addition, I have to mention, that an `\mbox{}` command will occur writing further along the end of the line.

So is there someone who knows that problem, respectively how to solve it? 
It's important because a manual line break yields a white space at the end of the line and this is strongly undesired.

Comment: Does `${C^{1,\beta}\times C^{0,\beta}}$\penalty10000 -\hskip0pt Topology` produce better line breaking?

Comment: With a long piece of mathematics that has no natural line break there is no automated solution. You could display the formula in an `equation*` environment, or reword the surrounding text so that the characters come in the middle of a line.

Comment: `-` disables line break in words that contain them, but you can manually add discretionary hyphens with `\-`, for instance `$C^{1,\beta}\times C^{0,\beta}$-Topol\-ogy`.

Comment: Dividing the word is similarly undesired. E.g., there is a situation in my text, where the "C" of `$C^[1,\bet...$` marks the last sign of the line, so for TeX it should be easy to take it in the new line and rearrange the previous part of the text to fill the whole line. The fact, that this only happens when `\times` is uses stresses, that there should be a workaround.

Comment: you can force a line break without leaving the line short with `\newline` (`\linebreak` and `\\ ` leave the line short)

Comment: tex will not stretch white space more than is specified, so if you want to avoid manual linebreaks but allow inter-word spaces to stretch to give more line break possibilities use `\sloppy`

Comment: If you don't want it broken at all, you can put it in a box. Not sure if this is what you don't want, though.

Comment: boxes like \mbox{} will not take the the overhanging part and put it into the new line. They will take the rest and put it further to the overhanging line. And \newline starts a new paragraph, where no new paragraph is needed.

Comment: You might try \sloppy.

Comment: `\sloppy` doesn't have any noticeable effect to my text, or am I using the wrong syntax? Even if I put the command in front of the critical part, there is no effect.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not clear but I assume that you get the 4th case, with the linebreak after `\times`

[image]

You can use `\nobreak` with the mathematics to stop the break there, if the break before `-topology` is not wanted you can force a linebreak with `\linbreak` (rather than `\\`) this does not leave the line short but instead over-stretches the line but is I think the output that you want here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

The subset $\Xi\subseteq C^{1,\alpha}\times C^{0,\alpha}$ is closed with
respect to the $C^{1,\beta}\times C^{0,\beta}$-Topology


xxThe subset $\Xi\subseteq C^{1,\alpha}\times C^{0,\alpha}$ is closed with
respect to the $C^{1,\beta}\times C^{0,\beta}$-Topology

xxxxxThe subset $\Xi\subseteq C^{1,\alpha}\times C^{0,\alpha}$ is closed with
respect to the $C^{1,\beta}\times C^{0,\beta}$-Topology

xxxxxxxxThe subset $\Xi\subseteq C^{1,\alpha}\times C^{0,\alpha}$ is closed with
respect to the $C^{1,\beta}\times C^{0,\beta}$-Topology


xxxxxxxxThe subset $\Xi\subseteq C^{1,\alpha}\times C^{0,\alpha}$ is closed with
respect to the $C^{1,\beta}\times\nobreak C^{0,\beta}$-Topology


xxxxxxxxThe subset $\Xi\subseteq C^{1,\alpha}\times C^{0,\alpha}$ is closed with
respect to the\linebreak $C^{1,\beta}\times  C^{0,\beta}$-Topology
\end{document}
```